# Decomposition of the matrix exponential (of the covariance matrix)

Tags: statistics, exponentiation, matrix-decomposition, covariance, matrix-exponential

The sample covariance matrix $\Sigma$ (chosen because it is symmetric and, therefore, diagonalizable) can be decomposed as

$$\Sigma = \text{diag}(\sigma) C \text{diag}(\sigma)$$
where $\text{diag}(\sigma)$ is a matrix with volatilities along the diagonal, and $C$ is the correlation matrix.

#### Question

If we compute the matrix exponential of the covariance matrix, $$e^\Sigma = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} \Sigma^k$$
does it too have a unique decomposition?

#### Attempt

Eigenvectors might indicate a possible answer regarding some link, since

$$\Sigma = PDP^{-1}$$
$$e^\Sigma = Pe^DP^{-1}$$

where $D = \text{diag}(\lambda_1, ..., \lambda_n)$ is a diagonal matrix whose entries are the eigenvalues of $\Sigma$, $e^D = \text{diag}(e^{\lambda_1}, ..., e^{\lambda_n})$, and $P$ contains eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalues.

This is unlike my case though because I am not interested in eigenvalues, only the actual matrix, or the matrix exponential of any symmetric matrix. Nevertheless, this is the only decomposition I know of so far, so someone could confirm that it is the only one out there

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\Sigma = PDP^{-1}$. Look at your formula for $e^{\Sigma}$. Note that
$$\Sigma^k = \left(PDP^{-1}\right)^k=PDP^{-1}PDP^{-1}\dots PDP^{-1}=PD^kP^{-1}.$$
So we have $$e^{\Sigma}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{k!}\Sigma^k=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{k!}PD^kP^{-1}=P\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{k!}D^k\right)P^{-1}=Pe^{D}P^{-1}.$$
And because $D$ is diagonal, $D^k$ and hence $e^D$ are really easy to compute: just take $D$, and raise the diagonal entries to the power of $k$ (for $D^k$) or exponentiate them (for $e^D$).

Comment: this was already known and written in the question. do you know of any other decompositions of the matrix exponential, perhaps pertaining to the covariance matrix exponential

Comment: @develarist up to permuting the entries along the diagonal, no. The entries of the diagonalised matrix must be the eigenvalues of the original matrix. This is true for any (diagonalisable) matrix, it has nothing to do with exponentials.